# Upgrading audio code to new WASAPI standard

Tags: audio, wasapi

We have an application that uses `waveXXX()` and `mixerXXX()` functions to handle the audio I/O to and from some instruments (think: oscilloscope or electronics rather than musical instruments, not that it much matters). It's finally time to stop deploying it on Windows XP, and move it to Windows 7 and/or 8.

From reading a variety of material on WASAPI, it sounds like the bulk of the application (based on `waveXXX()` functions) might actually work fine, but the `mixer()` stuff used to set master output volume, line in volume, and mute the microphone will definitely have to change, and use [IAudioEndPointVolume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calls instead.

Is it possible to change only the `mixerXXX()` calls? Is it desirable?

Logically, this application requires exclusive use of its audio endpoints (speaker out, line in). If I want to ensure exclusive access through software, would that force me to rewrite all the `waveXXX()` code too? (The alternative is to warn users that other audio applications may interfere with this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation:

- If you need exclusive access, convert everything to WASAPI
- If you are using line-in, convert everything to WASAPI
- If you have time, convert everything to WASAPI
- If you are strictly only using speaker and microphone in shared mode, replace `mixerXXX()` with the `ISimpleAudioVolume` interface (and several other interfaces to get to it), then test whether existing `waveXXX()` code behaves as you need it to. Then test each time hardware, OS or audio drivers change. Better still, just convert to WASAPI.

In my case, exclusive speaker output is critical - this drives the instrument that generates a related input signal. I guess I don't mind if another application wants to share access to that incoming signal, but logically it is a system that wants an exclusive contract with its audio endpoints.

That exclusivity requires that I obtain an `IMMDevice` instance for both speaker output and line-in input, `Activate()` the `IAudioClient` interface on them and `Initialize()` both using `AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977544/how-to-select-line-in-audio-input-and-set-input-volume-level/29156760#29156760)).

But have I actually selected line-in by such a process? Probably not. All I can be sure of is annoying any other applications who were previously sharing my endpoints by cutting them off.

Having done this much, it's really not clear what will happen to `waveInXXX()` calls - maybe they'll take from line-in, maybe from microphone - maybe it depends on how the hardware vendor implements their end of the deal. It's also never been clear to me whether line-in and microphone are always multiplexed (i.e. selectable), always mixed (i.e. you can only simulate selection by muting the other one) or there is no standard one can rely on.

Because of factors like that, it's a gamble not to use WASAPI throughout.

Comment: P.S. I found the process of converting from `waveXXX()` and `mixerXXX()` torturous, chiefly because the MS documentation comes across as an enormous collection of trees without ever quite being a coherent forest. But eventually I came to recognise WASAPI as a significant improvement... that would benefit considerably from some simpler and clearer examples.